# Can we connect to Spark cluster from remote host via java program?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to connect to spark cluster from remote system. My java code is shown below.

**JAVA Code**

```
new SparkConf()
   .setAppName("Java API demo")
   .setMaster("spark://192.168.XX.XX:7077")
   .set("spark.driver.host","192.168.XX.XX")
   .set("spark.driver.port","9929");
```

It gives me this error:

**Error Message**

> 16/04/14 16:08:42 ERROR NettyTransport: failed to bind to /192.168.XX.XX:9929, shutting down Netty transport 
>   16/04/14 16:08:42 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 9929. Attempting port 9930. 
>   16/04/14 16:08:42 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.

First of all, is this possible in spark? I am using Spark 1.4 version. Thanks in advcance..

Comment: As mentioned here (bullet number 4) http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html 
I dont see why you cannot. 
Just check that the firewall on both your local machine and your server enable you to do so.